# jQuery not working on any element inside a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here's my HTML code inside the form tag:

```
<section id="mp-cart-after" class="mp_cart_after">
            <div id="mp-checkout-payment-form">
            <h3 class="mp_sub_title">Payment</h3>
```

And here's the JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mp_sub_title').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.mp_sub_title').hide();
    });

});
```

I have tested jQuery on elements outside this form and it works.            `

Comment: The form is too long, I just pasted a snippet from that form. Basically, that is a payment and checkout form.

Comment: Yes, I have this HTML.

Comment: are there any errors in your developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX , there are no errors on the console.

Comment: once it works, a warning ... `jQuery('.mp_sub_title').hide();` will hide ALL elements with that class ... if you just want to hide the one that is clicked use `$(this).hide()` ... and another thing, your code will only hide the `<h3>` element - is that what you intended?

Comment: is the form dynamically created (eg, using ajax)

Comment: @JaromandaX  I don't want to hide anything, that is only to test whether jQuery works inside form. I have even tried `window.alert('works');`

Comment: ok ... so, is the form dynamically generated?

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes it is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the form is dynamically generated, you need to use delegated .on('click'

like so:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').on('click', '.mp_sub_title', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.mp_sub_title').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please change `on('click` to `on('click'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot some closing tags. However this works:

```
<form>
            <section id="mp-cart-after" class="mp_cart_after"></section>
            <div id="mp-checkout-payment-form">
            <h3 class="mp_sub_title">Payment</h3></div>
</form>
```

and

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".mp_sub_title").click(
            function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               jQuery('.mp_sub_title').hide();
            }            
        );
    });
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/3521/)

Comment: No, everything is closed properly, I just pasted the snippet from form, the form is too long.

Comment: Yes maybe. But somewhere in your long form is a mistake. As you see, my code works. Just try your code with only a few lines and then look when it stops working after you start adding more things